# Add or multiply a different value by factor level

Tags: r, r-factor

Is there a smarter way than the following to do a simple arithmetic operation to a data frame column by a factor level?

```
data <- runif(100,0,1)
df <- data.frame(x = data,
                 class = cut(data, breaks = c(0,0.5,1), labels = c("low", "high")))
df$x2 <- ifelse(df$class == "high", df$x - 1, df$x + 1)
```

I have a data frame with several factor levels and would like to add / multiply the values with a vector of different values. I though maybe something with `split` could work?

Comment: not very clear what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's make use of the internal integer representation of a factor:

```
df$x2 <- with(df, c(1, -1)[class] + x)
```

I don't recommend using `df` and `class` as variable names however, as they are aliased to R base functions. (Don't use `data` for the same reason.)

Some explanation here. You have coded `class` with factor levels "low" and "high", so they map to 1 and 2. Try `as.integer(df$class)` to see this. Now, your code suggest you want to add 1 to `x` for "low" and subtract 1 from `x` for "high", so we dispatch the increment vector `c(1, -1)` according to factor levels, then add it to `x`.

Comment: Thanks, i ll try to avoid to name variables like this in the future, it was just for the MWE anyway. 

That seems to work and would applies for several labels as well, e.g. three levels and using 
    with(df, c(1,0,1)[class] + x)

Comment: Cool I did not know you could subset based on the internal integer representation of a factor